# NSTimer not repeating from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

why would this not repeat when place in appDidFinishLaunching?

```
self.ti = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10. target:self selector:@selector(bounce:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[self.ti fire];
```

many thanks

Jules

Comment: What is the code in 'bounce'? Also, how are you setting up 'ti'.

Comment: in bounce i am simply logging at the moment to see if it is being called, ti is a property in my header (strong, nonatomic) and synthesized. It appears the code isnt even firing once let alone repeating? Many thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `bounce` has a wrong signature. It should be

```
- (void)bounce:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    NSLog(@"Here...");
}
```

You should be using `selector(bounce:)` to schedule this method. You should also be calling `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` instead of `timerWithTimeInterval`:

```
self.ti = [NSTimer
    scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.
                            target:self
                          selector:@selector(bounce:)
                          userInfo:nil
                           repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it will help, but try using `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method. An example:

```
self.ti = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10. target:self selector:@selector(bounce) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Hope it helps